# AEAD authentication with huge input that doesn't fit into RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto, aes-gcm

Say I've got a file on disk that doesn't fit in the computer's main memory. The file consists of two sections, a small section of less than 100 bytes at the beginning of the file, and a large section, consisting of the rest of the file.

I need to use AEAD (either ChaCha20-Poly1305 or AES-GCM) to encrypt the small section and authenticate the large section.

As far as I understand AEAD, in principle it should be possible to do this by loading the file into RAM piece-by-piece in small parts.

My problem is that the Python Cryptography AEAD API doesn't seem to be designed for this usecase, or at least it's missing similar examples.

This is the API documentation for ChaCha20-Poly1305: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.ChaCha20Poly1305

The docs indicate that the `associated_data` (input that needs to be authenticated, but not encrypted) parameter must be a bytes-like object, defined here: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/glossary/#term-bytes-like

They further point to the Python Buffer Protocol: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html

Ideas for a solution:

1. Hash the large section and only authenticate the resulting digest. I'm wary of doing this as I'm not entirely sure about the security implications, although it seems like it would be OK.
2. Construct a bytes-like type that would represent the large section without trying to load it into memory all at once. I have little experience with Python so I'm not sure how to proceed in this direction.

EDIT: the first idea is fine: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/269129/aead-authenticating-a-digest-of-my-data-instead-the-data-itself

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [cross posted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/269129) on Information Security and already answered there.

Comment: @Topaco The answer on the Security Stack Exchange does *not* answer this question, it merely says that the first idea is OK from a security perspective. There's still a lot left unanswered, even more when taking into account the comments on the Security Stack Exchange question.

Comment: *This* question is about how best to solve this *in Python*, taking into account the limitations of Python and the Cryptography library.

Comment: It's still not clear whether it's better to use my first or my second idea, or some other idea, or perhaps the stuff in the comments of the Security Stack Exchange question.

Comment: The comments there make it clear that the first idea is *not* a very good solution for performance.

Comment: Your *EDIT* is misleading in my opinion. I understood it to mean that the question had been answered in the meantime. I have retracted my *close* vote.

Comment: pyca/cryptography does not seem to allow a successive loading of the AAD, so the 2nd approach is presumably not possible, but only the first. PyCryptodome seems to allow successive loading of the AAD, e.g. for [GCM](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html?highlight=gcm%20mode#gcm-mode). So PyCryptodome could be an option that seems to be better tailored to your problem.